# Jquery UI sortable state on mouseup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Trying to check the state of some li elements after sorting with jquery UI sortable functionality.

```
$('#sortable').sortable()
$('#sortable').find('li').mouseup(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent())
})
```

I get the state of the parent just before I reordered the list elements. When I perform a move again it gives me the previous state. If i click with no change. I see the state/order of the elements as I expect.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Refer to API, in particular [the events](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to use a [stop function](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/JFGb4/1/)**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#sortable").sortable({
         stop: function (event, ui) {  //important bit
             alert($('#sortable').find('li').text());
         }
     });
     $("#sortable").disableSelection();
 });
```

Or an [update function](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) like this:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#sortable").sortable({
         update: function (event, ui) {  //important bit
             alert($('#sortable').find('li').text());
         }
     });
     $("#sortable").disableSelection();
 });
```

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/JFGb4/2/)**